Mechanism of Jones oxidation
We were required to find the number of moles of $CrO_3$ required to oxidize 6 moles of heptan-2-ol. I tried balancing the equation but I am not aware of the final chromium containing product. Knowing the mechanism would help answer this questions quickly but I was unable to find it in any source I have access to. Can someone help? Thank you.

Are there given the reaction conditions?

No they weren't mentioned in the question :(

Though in our curriculum, we take the solvent medium as acetone unless mentioned to be acidic.

Does this help?

Yes, thank you so much!

Wikipedia has rudimentary mechanism and also points to OCP. Not sure how one can miss that.

@andselisk I generally refer to my notes provided by my teacher and some other coursebooks. Given that I have a major exam in less than a week, I would prefer to use the next resource that I use often. Thank you for the link though.

The Name Reactions webpage gives acceptable mechanism to Jones Reaction, which is an organic reaction used to oxidize organic alcohols using chromic trioxide $(\ce{CrO3})$. in the presence of acid (often $\ce{H2SO4}$) in water. The mechanism begins with the reaction of $\ce{CrO3}$ with acid $(\ce{H2SO4})$ to form chromic acid or dichromic acid in more concentrated solutions:

The $1^\circ$- or  $2^\circ$- alcohol oxidation then occurs with newly formed chromic acid which in turn gets reduced in the process (Ref.1). The oxidation of $2^\circ$- alcohol is shown in following scheme:

Since your alcohol is a $2^\circ$- alcohol, you need a little more than $\pu{6 mol}$ of Jones reagent for complete oxidation.

References:

Kenneth Bowden, I. M. Heilbron, E. R. H. Jones, and B. C. L. Weedon, "13. Researches on acetylenic compounds. Part I. The preparation of acetylenic ketones by oxidation of acetylenic carbinols and glycols," J. Chem. Soc. 1946, 39-45 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/JR9460000039).

